# Javascript remove multiple html list elements

Tags: javascript

On every change of input, i need to remove **all** `<li>` elements where inner text don't match the input value. The problem is: it don't remove all lines that doesn't match at once.

My code:

```
        <input name="tag-input" id="tag-input" type='text'>
    <div id="list-pol">
        <ul id="list-pol-select">
            <li class="list-pol-item">Fish</li>
            <li class="list-pol-item">Dog</li>
            <li class="list-pol-item">Chameleon</li>
            <li class="list-pol-item">Cat</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var input = document.getElementById('tag-input');

        function updateList(){
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("list-pol-item")[0]){

                var list = document.getElementsByClassName("list-pol-item");

                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var tag = list.item(i).innerText;
                    if(input.value !== tag.substring(0,input.value.length)){
                        list.item(i).remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        input.addEventListener('input', updateList);
    </script>
```

Comment: Instead of `list.item(i)` you could just do `list[i]`. What is the if statement for in `updateList()`? It seems redundant...

Comment: I put the the if statement in case there's no list elements to iterate.

Comment: If there are no elements left to iterate the loop will not iterate (`i < 0 == false`), so it's definitely redundant... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will give you a live collection, which is very confusing. If the `i`th element in the collection loses the class name, the collection will lose that element and shift down *immediately*. If that happens while you're trying to iterate over it - like here - you'll be in trouble.

```js
const foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
foos[0].remove();
console.log(foos.length);
console.log(foos[0]);
```

```html
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
```

Turn it into a (non-live) array instead first - or use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a static NodeList.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('tag-input');

function updateList() {
  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.list-pol-item')) {
    if (!item.textContent.startsWith(input.value)) {
      item.remove();
    }
  }
}

input.addEventListener('input', updateList);
```

```html
<input name="tag-input" id="tag-input" type='text'>
<div id="list-pol">
  <ul id="list-pol-select">
    <li class="list-pol-item">Fish</li>
    <li class="list-pol-item">Dog</li>
    <li class="list-pol-item">Chameleon</li>
    <li class="list-pol-item">Cat</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you paste in "Fish", you'll see that Fish is the only item that remains.

But your current logic is weird - do you really want to `.remove()` the items that don't match? Unless someone pastes in text that matches exactly, everything will be removed. Did you want to toggle the items' display instead?

```js
var input = document.getElementById('tag-input');

function updateList() {
  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.list-pol-item')) {
    item.classList.toggle('hidden', !item.textContent.startsWith(input.value));
  }
}

input.addEventListener('input', updateList);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="tag-input" id="tag-input" type='text'>
<div id="list-pol">
  <ul id="list-pol-select">
    <li class="list-pol-item">Fish</li>
    <li class="list-pol-item">Dog</li>
    <li class="list-pol-item">Chameleon</li>
    <li class="list-pol-item">Cat</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You also might consider comparing the lower-cased input against the lower-cased list item, instead of requiring a case match for the elements to display.

Comment: List items will be dynamically generated, I think would be better to remove instead of toggle display but please correct me if i'm wrong. I use substring to match the first characters of the list not the entire word.

Comment: If `.remove()` is what your app requires, go for it. Yeah, I just saw the `===` and missed that you were checking the substring - if you want to check that one string starts with another, use `startsWith` instead.

Comment: Can you point the difference between ```textContent``` and ```innerText```?

Comment: `.textContent` is quicker and much more predictable. http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/